# Parse XML file to copy the content into another file at a particular spot in the file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, perl

I have an xml file `(client_23.xml)` in which I need to add few lines at a particular section basis on what is there in other xml file `(abc_lop.xml)`.

Here is my `abc_lop.xml` file in which you see I have lot of `ClientField` lines with `name`, `pptype` and `dataType` in it.

```
<Hello version="100">
 <DataHolder numberOfFields="67">
  <ClientField name="target" pptype="aligning" dataType="string">
   <Value value="panel_3646"/>
   <Value value="panel_3653"/>
  </ClientField>
  <ClientField name="category_3652_0_count" pptype="symetrical" dataType="double"/>
  <ClientField name="category_3652_2_count" pptype="symetrical" dataType="double"/>
  <ClientField name="category_3646_0_count" pptype="symetrical" dataType="double"/>
  <ClientField name="pme.cdert" pptype="symetrical" dataType="double"/>
  <ClientField name="pme.age" pptype="symetrical" dataType="double"/>
  <ClientField name="category_3648_1_count" pptype="symetrical" dataType="double"/>
  <ClientField name="pme.number" pptype="symetrical" dataType="double"/>
  <ClientField name="pme.gender" pptype="aligning" dataType="string">
   <Value value=""/>
   <Value value="F   "/>
   <Value value="NA"/>
  </ClientField>
  <ClientField name="pme.status" pptype="aligning" dataType="string">
   <Value value=""/>
   <Value value="A"/>
   <Value value="S"/>
   <Value value="NA"/>
  </ClientField>
  <ClientField name="pme.selling_id" pptype="aligning" dataType="string">
   <Value value="c0"/>
   <Value value="c1"/>
   <Value value="NA"/>
  </ClientField>
 </DataHolder>
</Hello>
```

I need to read this file and extract `name` from those `ClientField` lines and if its `pptype` is not `aligning` then I need to construct this line for each name: Below is an example for two names, only first value is different and apart from that other two will always be same.

```
<eval>upsert("category_3652_0_count", 0, $calty_doubles)</eval>
<eval>upsert("category_3652_2_count", 0, $calty_doubles)</eval>
```

Now if its `pptype` is `aligning`, then construct line like this:

```
<eval>upsert("target", "NA", $calty_strings)</eval>
<eval>upsert("pme.gender", "NA", $calty_strings)</eval>
```

And all these changes I have to make in `client_23.xml` file and then make a new file with it so my new file will look like this as an example: I will have a function with name `data_values` in which I need to add above stuff in the `<block>` tag as shown below.

```
    <function>
        <name>data_values</name>
        <variables>
            <variable>
            <name>temp</name>
            <type>double</type>
            </variable>
        </variables>
        <block>
            <eval>temp = 1</eval>
            <eval>upsert("category_3652_0_count", 0, $calty_doubles)</eval>
            <eval>upsert("category_3652_2_count", 0, $calty_doubles)</eval>
            <eval>upsert("target", "NA", $calty_strings)</eval>
            <eval>upsert("pme.gender", "NA", $calty_strings)</eval>             
        </block>
    </function>
```

This is what I have currently in `client_23.xml` file so after adding, it will look like above:

```
    <function>
        <name>data_values</name>
        <variables>
            <variable>
            <name>temp</name>
            <type>double</type>
            </variable>
        </variables>
        <block>
            <eval>temp = 1</eval>
        </block>
    </function>
```

I have a very simple shell script which terdon helped me earlier in which we are using perl script as shown below. I adding header and footer in the `abc_lop.xml` file and then storing it in `file` variable and then using that file value to put at a particular section in `client_23.xml` file but I am not sure how to do above things.

**SCRIPT:-**

```
for word in $client_types
do
    ## Concatenate the header, the contents of the target file and the
    ## footer into the variable $file.
    file=$(printf '%s\n%s\n%s' "$header" "$(cat "$path/${word}_lop.xml")" "$footer")

    ## Edit the target file and print
    perl -0pe "s#<eval>planting_model = 0</eval>#<eval>planting_model = 1</eval> s#<trestra-config>.* </trestra-config>##sm;   s#<function>\s*<name>DUMMY_FUNCTION.+?</function>#$file#sm" client_"$client_id".xml > "$word"_new_file.xml
done
```

Here `client_types` will be like this: `abc def pqr` and `$client_id` is 23.

Now I need to add above functionality which I am not sure how can I do that easily?

Answer (score 3):

Here's the Perl solution that I tried to post on Stack Overflow before you deleted your duplicate question

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML;

# Open the main XML file and locate the
# <block> element that we need to insert into
#
my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(
    location => 'client_23.xml',
    no_blanks => 1,
);
my $block = $doc->find('/function/block')->get_node(1);

# Open the secondary XML file and find all the <ClientField> elements
# that contain the data we need to insert
#
my $abc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => 'abc_lop.xml');

for my $field ( $abc->find('/Hello/DataHolder/ClientField')->get_nodelist ) {

    my ($name, $pptype) = map $field->getAttribute($_), qw/ name pptype /;

    my $text = $pptype eq 'aligning' ?
        sprintf q{upsert("%s", "NA", $calty_strings)}, $name :
        sprintf q{upsert("%s", 0, $calty_doubles)}, $name;

    $block->appendTextChild('eval' , $text);
}

print $doc->toString(2);
```

#### output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<function>
  <name>data_values</name>
  <variables>
    <variable>
      <name>temp</name>
      <type>double</type>
    </variable>
  </variables>
  <block>
    <eval>temp = 1</eval>
    <eval>upsert("target", "NA", $calty_strings)</eval>
    <eval>upsert("category_3652_0_count", 0, $calty_doubles)</eval>
    <eval>upsert("category_3652_2_count", 0, $calty_doubles)</eval>
    <eval>upsert("category_3646_0_count", 0, $calty_doubles)</eval>
    <eval>upsert("pme.cdert", 0, $calty_doubles)</eval>
    <eval>upsert("pme.age", 0, $calty_doubles)</eval>
    <eval>upsert("category_3648_1_count", 0, $calty_doubles)</eval>
    <eval>upsert("pme.number", 0, $calty_doubles)</eval>
    <eval>upsert("pme.gender", "NA", $calty_strings)</eval>
    <eval>upsert("pme.status", "NA", $calty_strings)</eval>
    <eval>upsert("pme.selling_id", "NA", $calty_strings)</eval>
  </block>
</function>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and your time, do you see we can integrate this in my shell script somehow? I need to make sure this line `## Edit the target file and print
    perl -0pe "s#<eval>planting_model = 0</eval>#<eval>planting_model = 1</eval> s#<trestra-config>.* </trestra-config>##sm;   s#<function>\s*<name>DUMMY_FUNCTION.+?</function>#$file#sm" client_"$client_id".xml > "$word"_new_file.xml` should use the file that gets generated from your step.

Comment: @david ugh. That's seriously unreadable as a comment

Comment: okkk.. What I meant was my `perl` command is working on original `client_23.xml` file. What might work is, instead of my perl command working on original `client_23.xml` file, it should work on xml file generated by Borodin step and combine everything in one shell script.

Comment: I need to have everything in one shell script and then I will make that shell script in one line with all escaped strings.

Answer (score 1):

Not perl though, I prefer python for quick xml modifications. Eg:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

file1 = sys.argv[1]
file2 = sys.argv[2]

abc = ET.parse(file1).getroot()
xml2 = ET.parse(file2).getroot()

# For ClientField[name] properties
l = []

block = xml2.find('block')

for node in abc.findall("*/ClientField"):
    if node.attrib['pptype'] == 'aligning':
        ET.SubElement(block, 'eval').text = 'upsert("' + node.get('name') + '", "NA", $calty_strings)'
    else:
        ET.SubElement(block, 'eval').text = 'upsert("' + node.get('name') + '", 0, $calty_doubles)'

print(ET.tostring(xml2))
```

This will give you:

```
<function>
    <name>data_values</name>
    <variables>
        <variable>
            <name>temp</name>
            <type>double</type>
        </variable>
    </variables>
    <block>
        <eval>temp = 1</eval>
        <eval>upsert("target", "NA", $calty_strings)</eval>
        <eval>upsert("category_3652_0_count", 0, $calty_doubles)</eval>
        <eval>upsert("category_3652_2_count", 0, $calty_doubles)</eval>
        <eval>upsert("category_3646_0_count", 0, $calty_doubles)</eval>
        <eval>upsert("pme.cdert", 0, $calty_doubles)</eval>
        <eval>upsert("pme.age", 0, $calty_doubles)</eval>
        <eval>upsert("category_3648_1_count", 0, $calty_doubles)</eval>
        <eval>upsert("pme.number", 0, $calty_doubles)</eval>
        <eval>upsert("pme.gender", "NA", $calty_strings)</eval>
        <eval>upsert("pme.status", "NA", $calty_strings)</eval>
        <eval>upsert("pme.selling_id", "NA", $calty_strings)</eval>
    </block>
</function>
```

*EDIT*:
The shell script will look like this:

```
client_id=23

for word in $client_types
do
    python converter.py $path/${word}_lop.xml client_"$client_id".xml
done
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. How can I integrate this in my shell script. I need to have everything at one place as you can see in my above shell script. I am doing other stuff as well with same files.

Comment: May be use Python for this and Perl for other stuff which I am doing?

Comment: I recommend passing in the filenames as parameters then.

Comment: See changed code above, use sys.argv[], then you just call the python script with the appropriate xml names.

Comment: hmmm, problem is I need to have everything in one shell script and then I need to convert that shell script in one line and put it on some other place and then I am executing it.

Comment: If the job is just to convert the xmls then why don't you distribute the python script instead?

Comment: but if we add another server then we need to distribute again this script. But as of now, if we have everything in one script and then I convert it into one line and store it on zookeeper and then my program is generic because I will get this one line shell script from zookeeper and just execute it from java.

Comment: Well... that's a whole different situation that you described in the OP. You can do it in Java then, or even better, write an xslt and execute that in the distributed java application. But I strongly recommend not going in the 1 line-perl script-in-bash-run-by-Java world.